# How to count unique values w.r.t one column in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find the number of unique values in column B("Levels") for each value in column A("Heads").

For example for Heads "A" we have 3 unique values ("ALPHA", "BETA", "ECHO") and it should return in column "Expected Count".

```
Heads   Levels  Expected Count
A   ALPHA   3
A   ALPHA   3
A   BETA    3
A   ECHO    3
B   CHARLIE 2
B   CHARLIE 2
B   DELTA   2
C   ALPHA   4
C   BETA    4
C   CHARLIE 4
C   DELTA   4
```

I need to execute the functionality for 1000's of rows. Is there any formula?

Comment: There are filters for that, but they wont count or output for you. Just filter/style them differently. See the official office docs: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2

Comment: Yes, there is a formula; there are also pivot tables.

Answer (score 0):

you need one new column. insert it between B and C. concatenate column a and b with formula

=a&b

then do a simple formula in column d and drag that down on your 1000's of rows

=countifs(C:C,C2)